# Could adding a framework to an iOS project block/hide access to other files in the project?

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks, dropbox-api, glkit

After adding the Dropbox SDK Framework to my Xcode project (iOS) my project fails to build due to errors shown in image 1 below:

[image: Screen shot of the errors seen after adding Dropbox SDK Framework]

Prior to adding the Dropbox Framework, or reverting to the previous commit, results in the project building and running with out issue. I have also tested the same Dropbox SDK Framework package in a seperate demo project to ensure it is not corrupted - and that demo project builds and runs just fine, accessing the Dropbox SDK as expected.

Is it possible that the Dropbox SDK Framework is hiding or blocking access to the GLKit Framework within my main project?

Or is there something else at play here? The second error shown in screenshot claims the bridging header also 'Failed to import' which is an error I have not seen before, usually it is 'not found'.

The Dropbox SDK Framework is being added by drag-and-dropping into Xcode and checking the copy if needed box. Immediately after adding the Dropbox SDK Framework the project no longer builds and reports these errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am answering my own question for anyone else who might have similar problems. While I did not find the root cause of the problem, I did get around it with the following solution.

I ended up removing all third party frameworks from my project which were:

- ResearchKit Framework
- Dropbox SDK Framework
- Charts Framework

And in addition I removed all the XCode supplied frameworks from the project in the left hand file list: 'Project Title -> General -> Linked Frameworks and Libraries'

I then installed and setup CocoaPods with the project, and used CocoaPods to install and manage my third party frameworks (ResearchKit, Dropbox SDK and Charts)

The project is now able to build and run successfully and has access to the GLKit framework along with all other XCode supplied frameworks, bridging header and Dropbox SDK.

I assume this issue was due to a setting in XCode that was preventing access to GLKit after the Dropbox SDK had been added, and using CocoaPods to manage the integration of the third party frameworks skirted this issue.

If anyone has any further insight I'd be very interested to hear you explanation.